# How is the area of this triangle calculated

Tags: inequality, triangles, area

I was reading "Problems of Calculus in one variable" by I A MARON,  and came across this solved example in first chapter which I am unable to comprehend, please help me understand this.

Scan of the example 1.2.7
[image: Problem scan]

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't ask a specific question--is there a specific step or steps you don't understand?

Comment: yes, the points In solution [<=sqrrt2], S(x)=S_delta_AMN=x^2. and then how is x>sqrrt2 and the second last since statement

Comment: What the author does is to divide the situation into 2 cases. If $x \le sqrt(2)$, then MN will not pass BD such that AMN remains in the form of a triangle. If otherwise, MN will cut the square into a pentagon ABMND. The area of which, of course, must be treated separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\le\sqrt{2}$ then the area is just $\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}=x^2$ which is base times height of both of the triangles $AEM$,$AEN$ added together. If $x>\sqrt{2}$ then it's the area of the square minus the area of the complement of $ADNMB$ which is the upper right triangle $NCM$. That's going to be:
$$
AB^2 - (DEC+ECB) = 4 - \frac{(2\sqrt{2}-x)^2}{2}\cdot 2= 4-(2\sqrt{2}-x)^2
$$